# Tamiyo's Journal and the Legend Rule

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-legendary-cards

The [Legend Rule](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/%22Legend_rule%22) states:

> If a player controls two or more legendary permanents with the same
>   name, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their
>   owners' graveyards.

[image]

This is just a rule clarification so my brother believes me, but is everything listed below legal?

- tap Tamiyo's Journal and sacrifice three clues to find another Tamiyo's
- play it for 5 mana and put the tapped Tamiyo's into the graveyard
- tap the untapped Tamiyos and sacrifice three more clues

Comment: That seems like a very inefficient way to tutor for a card.

Comment: "Is this legal?" leaves me wondering what parts of the scenario you need help with. I recommend asking a more specific question. For starters, ask yourself the question "Why would this not be legal?"'

Comment: @murgatroid99 I can tutor Emrakul on turn 5 with Tamiyos, but this above combo is for Tireless Tracker / Fleeting Memories.

Comment: I guess it does save 1 mana as compared to sacrificing each of the 3 clues to its own ability,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly legal, assuming that you started with 6 clue tokens. Hard to point to a specific rule saying so, but there's 2 things to keep in mind:

1 - The legend rule, which you quoted, doesn't say anything about restrictions on which of the duplicates you have to choose, so there's no reason you can't choose the tapped one to get rid of and the untapped one to keep.

2 - Tamiyo's Journal doesn't care where the clue tokens came from; it doesn't have to be the same tokens that it created.

Of course, as described, you will get no benefit from this: you'll have just wasted 3 clue tokens and 5 mana. But it could be good with various combinations.

Comment: It's very inefficient unless you have 5 mana and need all 6 clues to be sacrificed. Tireless Tracker or Mazirek come to mind.

Comment: Of course, I'd only do this if I have cards like Tireless Tracker / Fleeting Memories